# Socket.io and Node/Express - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm using react on front end and node/express on backend. I am trying to integrate sockets to make any click event done on one client be emitted on all the other clients. (ex. if someone clicks 'play song' it will trigger a click event for all the other users to play the song).

When I click on something, it doest reach the server's socket listener and displays Maximum call stack size exceeded in the browser's console.

PS: it's my first time importing code and it wont let me indent it!

Server Side code:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(8000);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('socket connected!');
    socket.on('myClick', function (data) {
        console.log('event hit Server');
        socket.broadcast.emit('myClick', data);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        io.emit('user disconnected');
    });
});
```

Client Side Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var socket = io('http://localhost:8000');

    $(document).on('click', function(event){
        console.log('Something has been clicked!');
        console.dir(event.target);
        socket.emit('myClick', {id: event.target});
    });
    socket.on('myClick', function (data) {
        console.log('event hit other client');
        $(data.id).trigger('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: Use spaces to indent.

Comment: Same error without the `console.dir` call?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is at the client side, you are causing an infinite loop of calls:

1. When clicking on the DOM, your "click" function is fired.
2. That function emits the socket's "myClick" event, so the "myClick" function is fired.
3. Inside this function you trigger a click event, and so, the previous function is fired again and you go back to step 1 infinitely.

**Solution**: replace the

```
$(document).on('click', function(event){
```

line with something more specific, like the id or the class of the element which has to fire the event:

```
$("#elementId").on('click', function(event){
```

Comment: Even then the client would still fire the click again but just for the specific element clicked. The client needs to differentiate between clicks its emitted and clicks another client has emitted. So the the socket on it only replicates clicks from a different client. But spot on with the recursion issue.